# What is discriminant and how is it derived for cubic equations?

Tags: cubics, discriminant

I have been studying on cubic equations and I have actually reached the cubic formula on my own, but I couldn't really understand what a discriminant is. I obtained the discriminant of a quadratic equation by replacing x with the vertex point of equation which is $-\frac b{2a}$. However when it is done to cubic equations, replacing x with $-\frac b{3a}$, which is the average of the sum of three roots, I don't know if what I got is the discriminant of cubic equations. What I got after replacing x with $-\frac b{3a}$ for $y=x^3+\frac b{a}x^2+\frac c{a}x+\frac d{a}$ is:

$$y = \frac{2b^3-9abc+27a^2d}{27a^3} = \Delta$$

I obtained $\Delta$ after replacing $-\frac b{2a}$ in quadratic equations and this is why I equalized them even if it may not be equal.

So, what I ask is what a discriminant really is and how we obtain it for cubic equations, with explanations. I also would like to see how it changes the graph if possible.

Comment: There's no $d$ in your formula.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown sorry, edited.

Comment: In [Brilliant's notation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/cubic-discriminant/), $\Delta_3:=b^2c^2-4ac^3-4b^3d-27a^2d^2+18abcd$, which has five terms. You should edit your question to show how you obtained your $\Delta$, which has three terms.

Comment: @J.G. is it also obtained by the replacement I did? I don't say this is the correct discriminant, I am asking if it is, and if not, how to obtain the correct one with explanations. I just checked the replacement I did and I didn't see any errors in it.

Comment: It seems you've tried to extend the fact that the quadratic $x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}$ is equal at $-\frac{b}{2a}$ to $\frac{-\Delta}{4a^2}$ to a definition of a cubic's determinant in terms of its value at $-\frac{b}{3a}$. [That's not the usual definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Definition).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the discriminant of a polynomial of degree $n$, $p(X)=a_nX^n+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\dots +a_0$, with coefficients in an integral domain $R$ of characteristic $0$, is defined by the following formula:
$$\Delta(P)=\frac{(-1)^{\tfrac{n(n-1)}2}}{a_n}\,R(P,P')$$
where  $R(P,P')$ denotes the *resultant* of $P$ and $P'$.

It is nonzero if and only if $P$ is a *separable* polynomial, i.e. if and only if it has no multiple roots in the algebraic closure of the fraction field of $R$.

Furthermore, if the roots of $P$ in this algebraic closure are $\alpha_1,\alpha_n,\dots,\alpha_n$, the discriminant is equal to
$$\Delta(P)=\alpha_n^{2n-2}\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}(\alpha_i-\alpha_j)^2.$$

Comment: You’re technically correct, but don’t you think this is a quite technical introduction to a subject most students first learn about in middle school?

Comment: @URL: The discriminant of a cubic polynomial in middle school???

Comment: I was talking about the quadratic polynomial discriminant. Surely if someone was asking about the general discriminant, it would be easier to start from there.

Comment: Of course for quadratic equations  (which are done high school , not middle school), this is irrelevant. But the question was about the general form of the discriminant for a cubic polynomial, which no one knows by heartl

Comment: Thank you for your concern. However I am a high school student and I have never seen such a notation before, so I can't really get the point of it. Could you please simplify this in a way that demostrates how the discriminant is derived for a cubic equation, maybe with references to how it is done to quadratics to make it even much more clear? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know about determinants, per chance?

Comment: Not much, maybe just that it refers to a matrix's numerical value?